# How to require files in a custom endpoint

Tags: ajax, uploads, rest-api, 500-internal-error, endpoints

I am working on a custom endpoint to handle ajax media uploads with `media_handle_upload()`.

I have created a custom endpoint with a route that is tested and works, however when I try require the necessary files so that I can use `media_handle_upload()`, it returns a 500 internal server error with each request but still uploads the media correctly in to the media library.

I have tried to figure this out for a while now but I dont understand why it's happening.

Hoping somebody here can point me in the right direction!

To clearify, everything works as expected, the internal server error does not hinder the upload to happen correctly, but the error occurs with every request, no matter what.

**Here is the function to upload: (*path to custom routes file = /inc/custom-routes/custom-route.php*)**

```
function uploadFileFE ($data) {

              if ( isset( $_FILES["file"] ) ) {

                require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
                require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
                require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';

                  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'file', 0 );

                  if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                      // There was an error uploading the image.
                      echo $attachment_id->get_error_message();
                  } else {
                      // The image was uploaded successfully!
                      echo $attachment_id;
                  }

              } else {

                  echo "The empty check failed! Something went horribly wrong!";
              }

             wp_die();

          }
```

**Update (*with working code, adjusted from answer below*)**

So, the answer that Sally CJ gave was correct, I'm updating with the new code so that if anyone else does the same mistake I did, they'll see the complete working code.

```
function uploadFileFE ($data) {

          if ( isset( $_FILES["file"] ) ) {

            //$glSiteUrl = get_site_url();

            // These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';

              $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'file', 0 );

              if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                  // There was an error uploading the image.
                  return $attachment_id->get_error_message();
              } else {
                  // The image was uploaded successfully!
                  return $attachment_id;
              }

          } else {

              return "The empty check failed! Something went horribly wrong!";
          }

        }
```

Comment: What's your `register_rest_route()` code? Is the `uploadFileFE` the endpoint callback? But even if not, you shouldn't call `wp_die()` or do `echo` there.

Comment: The route works fine. Yes, uploadFileFE is the callback. It's only when i require the files you see required in the function that things get messy. And I don't understand why. If i remove the require files, I get no error other than the undefined function of wp_handle_upload ofc, since it's dependencies is lacking without those files.

Comment: My answer might help? And in your code, you might want to use `require_once` instead of `require`... just in case.

Comment: Does the code definitely not work if you don't include the files? Have you confirmed that they need to be included?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The code does not work if the files are not included, no.

Comment: @SallyCJ I've tried require, require_once and even include and include_once, just to be sure. The same error occur no matter how the files are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `wp_die()` [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/#parameters),

> **$args**
>   *(string|array|int) (Optional)* Arguments to control behavior. If `$args` is an integer, then it is treated as the response code.
>
> '**response**'
>   *(int)* The HTTP response code. Default 200 for Ajax requests, 500 otherwise.

So your REST API endpoint returns the error `500` because that's the default header status sent by the `wp_die` function.

And I recommend you to return a [proper value](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value) — e.g. a `WP_Error` instance on error, or a `WP_REST_Response` instance on success. Try these variations and compare the responses:

**Option 1**

```php
// Works, but with a 500 status code.
function uploadFileFE() {
    wp_die();
}
```

**Option 2**

```php
// Works, but shouldn't be used unless the client is *not* expecting a JSON response.
function uploadFileFE() {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

**Option 3**

```php
// I'd use this. WordPress will apply rest_ensure_response() to the returned value.
function uploadFileFE() {
    return 'foo';
    //return WP_REST_Response( 'foo' ); // or use this, or below to send an error..
    //return new WP_Error( 'invalid_file', 'Invalid file!', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. The wp_die() function messed it up. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: :) I actually did test the function with just the `require` lines *without* the `wp_die();`, and confirmed the issue was the `wp_die();`.